# How do I clip a wireframe plot in the z direction?

Tags: r, plot, clipping, wireframe

How do I clip/crop a wireframe plot at the maximum value of the z axis?  For example:

```
library(lattice)
xy = expand.grid(x=1:5, y=1:5)
z = xy$x * xy$y
plot(wireframe(z ~ xy$x * xy$y, zlim=c(0,7), xlab="x", ylab="y", zlab="x*y",
  scales=list(x=list(arrows=FALSE),y=list(arrows=FALSE),
              z=list(arrows=FALSE,tick.number=5))))
```

`zlim[2] == 7`, so I'd like the plot to be clipped at 7 on the z-axis.  But this is what gets plotted:

[image: ActualPlot]

It appears that all grid points that connect to a point under the zlim get plotted and all other grid points above zlim get discarded.

I'd like the plot to have all edges cropped at the point that they cross the zlim, i.e., something like this:

[image: DesiredPlot]

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks,

John